# What would be the best/average/and worst case complexity (big O) for this method?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, equals, quadratic

```
// Checks if list contains a specific elements
public boolean contains(String it) {
    int index=front;
    while(index!=-1){
        if(dataList[index].equals(it)) {
            return true;
        }
        index= nextList[index];
    }
    return false;
}
```

how does the .equals() comparison method affect the algorithmic complexity? Does it turn it from linear to quadratic?

Comment: Can you define `front`, `dataList` and `nextList`? Regardless, `.equals(it)` is at least `O(lenght(it))`, so you need to multiply the number of iterations by that.

Comment: Of course, if `it` has a fixed maximum length, `O(length(it))` is the same as constant time...

Answer (score 0):

You should take .equals() as a basic step when analysing the runtime of this algorithm. the important thing for computing the runtime of the algorithm is the size of dataList and in this sense the size of "it" is constant.

The best case complexity is given by the case of finding the element in the first position, and then is O(1), the worst case is when you find the element in the last position, and then is O(n). The average case is given by  taking all the possibilities (that the element is in position one, or in position 2 and so on) and dividing by n, formally:

```
                      1+2+3+..+n/n
```

and this is O(n) too.